# how to pass a textfield to a title of a frame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to pass the Textfield text to a frame title. Please.

For example: if I write in the TextField "Hello", it should appear in the title of the Frame "Hello"

I have not found information in forums or support pages.

I will put the example code, what I need is on line 25 and 40.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class HELPME extends Frame{
    Frame frame2,frame3;
    Button Close,Close1;
    Label Student;
    TextField TStudent;
    String nombre;
    Button Result;


    public HELPME(){
        frame2=new Frame();
        frame2.setSize(300,150);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame2.setLayout(null);


        Student = new Label("Student: ");
        Student.setBounds(20, 50, 50, 30);
        frame2.add(Student);

        TStudent = new TextField();
        nombre=TStudent.getText();  // ¡¡HEREE!!  <--
        TStudent.setBounds(80, 50, 100, 30);
        frame2.add(TStudent);

        Result=new Button("Result");
        Result.setBounds(80, 100, 57, 30);
        frame2.add(Result);

        Result.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            frame3=new Frame();
                            frame3.setSize(500,150);
                            frame3.setVisible(true);
                            frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                            frame3.setLayout(null);
                            frame3.setTitle(nombre); // AND HERE <-- 

                    }
                  });
        //close the window
        frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
         } 
      });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    HELPME prog = new HELPME();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest taking it step by step. First learn [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

Comment: You try to use AWT lib. I would suggest you to use Swing instead. When you still need to use AWT, you can add a `TextListener` to your field, and when you get an event, you can update your frame title with the actual text value of your text field.

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. ..

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 5) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your requirement is to get the text from text field and set it as second window's title when user clicks the button.

You can do this by getting rid of the variable `nombre` and directly using `TStudent.getText()` to set the title.

I have only changed below line and it works:

```
frame3.setTitle(TStudent.getText()); // AND HERE <--
```

(I agree with the comments in the question. You should use correct Java coding conventions. Better to use Swing than AWT for Java GUIs if there isn't a particular reason for using AWT.)

Full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class HELPME extends Frame{
  Frame frame2,frame3;
  Button Close,Close1;
  Label Student;
  TextField TStudent;
  String nombre;
  Button Result;


  public HELPME(){
    frame2=new Frame();
    frame2.setSize(300,150);
    frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame2.setLayout(null);


    Student = new Label("Student: ");
    Student.setBounds(20, 50, 50, 30);
    frame2.add(Student);

    TStudent = new TextField();
    nombre=TStudent.getText();  // ¡¡HEREE!!  <--
    TStudent.setBounds(80, 50, 100, 30);
    frame2.add(TStudent);

    Result=new Button("Result");
    Result.setBounds(80, 100, 57, 30);
    frame2.add(Result);

    Result.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame3=new Frame();
        frame3.setSize(500,150);
        frame3.setVisible(true);
        frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame3.setLayout(null);
        frame3.setTitle(TStudent.getText()); // AND HERE <--

      }
    });
    //close the window
    frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    HELPME prog = new HELPME();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ¡Thank you very much!